# minizinc: find element in arrray

Tags: minizinc

I have two arrays(type: int) of different length. How could I find the closest number in array b for each number in array a(the following does not work though probably because of syntax error):

```
int: m;
int: n;
array [1..m] of int: a;
array [1..n] of int: b;
array[1..m] of int: results;
results = [abs(a[i] - b[j])| i in 1..m, j in 1..n];
solve minimize results;
output ["Solution: ", show(results)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It always helps with a complete model with as much information as possible, e.g. the values of "m" and "n" and other known/fixed values. Also, mention of the error messages helps in general.)

There are a couple of unknown things in your model, so I have to guess a little.

I guess that "results" really should be a single decision variable, and not an array as you defined it. Then you can write

```
var int: results = sum([abs(a[i] - b[j])| i in 1..m, j in 1..n]);
```

or

```
var int: results;
...
constraint results = sum([abs(a[i] - b[j])| i in 1..m, j in 1..n]);
```

Also, as it stand the model is not especially interesting since it just define two constant arrays "a" and "b" (which must be filled with constant values). I assume that at least one of them are meant to be decision variables. An array of decision variable must be declared with "var int" (or better: something like "var 1..size" where 1..size is the domain of possible values in the array).

Here is an example of a working model, which may or may not be something like what you have in mind:

```
int: m = 10;
int: n = 10;
array [1..m] of int: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
array [1..n] of var 1..10: b;
var int: results = sum([abs(a[i] - b[j])| i in 1..m, j in 1..n]);

solve minimize results;
output [
  "Solution: ", show(results),"\n",
  "a: ", show(a), "\n",
  "b: ", show(b), "\n",
  ];
```

**Update 2015-11-19:**

I'm not sure I've understand the requirements completely, but here is a variant. Note that the sum loop don't use the "b" array at all, just "a" and "results". To ensure that the values in "results" are selected from "b" the domain of "results" are simply the set of the values in "b".

```
int: m = 10;
int: n = 10;
array [1..m] of int: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
array [1..n] of int: b = [5,6,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

% decision variables

% values only from b
array[1..m] of var {b[i] | i in 1..n}: results;
var int: z; % to minimize

constraint
   z >= 0 /\
   z = sum(i in 1..m) (
     sum(j in 1..m) (abs(a[i]-results[j])) 
     % (abs(a[i]-results[i])) % alternative interpretation (see below)
   )
;

solve minimize z;

output [
  "z: ", show(z), "\n",
  "results: ", show(results),"\n",
  "a: ", show(a), "\n",
  "b: ", show(b), "\n",
];
```

Gecode has this for the optimal solution:

```
 z: 250
 results: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 b: [5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Another solver (Opturion CPX) has a solution more similar to your variant:

```
 z: 250
 results: [6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5]
 a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 b: [5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Note that both solutions has the same optimal objective value ("z") of 250.

There is, however, an alternative interpretation of the requirement (from your comment):

> for each element in a, select a corresponding value from b - this
>   value has to be the closest in value to each element in a.

where each value in "results" corresponds just the the value in "a" with the same index ("i") , i.e.

```
 % ...
 constraint
   z >= 0 /\
   z = sum(i in 1..m) (
      (abs(a[i]-results[i])) 
   )

 ;
```

The solution then is (Gecode):

```
z: 19
results: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 13]
a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b: [5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

The last value in "results" (13) is then chosen since it's nearer to 10 (last element in "a").

**Update 2 (2015-11-20)**

Regarding the second comment, about a 2D (not a 3D version you wrote), here's a model. It's based on the second interpretation of the model above. Extending it to larger dimensions is just a matter of changing the dimensions and adding the loop variables.

Note that this assumes - perhaps contrary to your original question - that the dimensions of "a" and "results" are identical. If they are not, the the second interpretation can not be the one you intend. Also, I changed the values in "a" and "b" to make it more interesting. :-)

```
int: m = 3;
int: n = 3;
array [1..m,1..n] of int: a = [|1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9|];
array [1..m,1..n] of int: b = [|5,6,13|14,15,16,|7,18,19|];

% decision variables

% values only from b
array[1..m,1..n] of var {b[i,j] | i in 1..m, j in 1..n}: results;
var int: z;

constraint
   z >= 0 /\
   z = sum(i in 1..m, j in 1..n) (
     (abs(a[i,j]-results[i,j]))
  )
;

solve minimize z;

output [  "z: ", show(z), "\n" ]
++["results:"]++
[
  if j = 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
    show_int(2,results[i,j])
  | i in 1..m, j in 1..n
]
++["\na:"]++
[
   if j = 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
      show_int(2,a[i,j])
   | i in 1..m, j in 1..n
]
++["\nb:"]++
[
   if j = 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
     show_int(2,b[i,j])
    | i in 1..m, j in 1..n
];
```

One optimal solution of this is this:

```
z: 13

results:
 5  5  5
 5  5  6
 7  7  7

a:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9

b:
 5  6 13
14 15 16
 7 18 19
```

Comment: more information(a, b are fixed arrays while results is an array of a's size and is to be filled by the program): for instance: array [1..m] of int: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];  array [1..n] of int: b = [5,6,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]; constraint: for each element in a, select a corresponding value from b - this value has to be the closest in value to each element in a - so the results will be [5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6]

Comment: The second interpretation really solved my problem. Super-clear answer! However, I still want to ask what if all the arrays are 3-d - in the sense that each element in the array will have three values:  [|1, 1, 1|2, 2, 2 |3, 3, 3|] - is it still possible to do such a search?

Comment: I'm (still) not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but I updated the answer with a 2D variant (not a 3D since your example is just a 2D matrix).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful! :) BTW, I also wonder if you know how to call a Minizinc model from a Java program with arrays as passed-on parameters? Is there any special command for doing this? :)

Comment: You asked the same thing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815339/call-minizinc-model-from-java . I wonder about what you mean more exactly. Please answer there.

Comment: Can I possibly call a minizinc model directly from the java program? If I can't- does it mean I have to run the minizinc model manually in order to process some data for my java program?